# Find the equation of a normal line without any functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I have the following here:

> Given differentiable functions $f$ and $g$, let $h = f \circ g$. The tangent line to the graph
> $y = g(x)$ at the point with $x = 4$ has the equation
> $$y = 4x − 2,$$
> while the tangent line to the graph $y = h(x)$ at the point $x = 4$ has the equation
> $$y = −2x + 18.$$
> a) Determine $g(4)$ and $f(g(4))$.
> b) Find an equation of the normal line to the graph $y = f(x)$ at the point $(g(4), f(g(4)))$.

Here's what I've tried.

a) Since the tangent line and the graph for $y=g(x)$ both have the exact same value at $x=4$, this means that $g(4)=4(4)-2=14$. Similarly, $f(g(4))=h(4)=-2(4)+18=10$.

b) In order to find the equation of the normal graph to $y=f(x)$ at $x=4$, I would need to know the equation of the tangent line at $x=4$ for $y=f(x)$ and then take the negative reciprocal. So that means I need $f'(4)$ right?

So that means I need the actual point of tangency since $g(4),f(g(4))$ isn't on the graph. So that means I can try the following.

Assume that the point of tangency is $k,f(k)$. That means we have:

$f(g(4))-f(k)=f'(4)(g(4)-k)$. In other words, I have:

$10-f(k)=f'(4)(14-k)$

I also know that $h=f(g(x))$ and $h'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. I thought I could use this to help me find $f'(4)$ and somehow use that to find the point of tangency, but I'm not sure how to put it all together I Suppose.

Can someone guide me? I feel like I am literally just missing one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal line we are looking for passes through the point
$\big(g(4), f(g(4))\big)=(14,10).$
Substituting $x=4,\; g(4)=14,\; g'(4)=4,\; h'(4)=-2\;$ in $$h'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
gives $$-2=4f'(14).$$ Thus $f'(14)=-1/2,$ which is the slope of the tangent line.
The slope of any line orthogonal to $y = kx + m$ with $k\neq0, m\in\mathbb{R},$ is
$-1/k.$

The normal line at the point $(14,10)$ has equation
$$y=2(x-14)+10.$$